# Outputing a square to console in java

Tags: java, algorithm

Hi i am doing my coursework and i have been given the task is to make an algorithm for a square that's 5x5 using "*" but has to be filled in with "." so like this:

```
*****
*...*
*...*
*...*
*****
```

I have used this code I know its probably very messy because im an absolute beginner to this stuff. I cant seem to get the "." in i currently have:

```
*****
*****
*****
*****
*****
```

here is my code:

```
public static void main( String args[] )
{
    System.out.print ("#size of square");
    int stars=BIO.getInt();
    int j=1;
    while(j <= stars)
    {
        int starsNumber=1;
        while (starsNumber<= stars)
        {
            int i = 1;                        // Display trunk
            starsNumber=starsNumber+1;
            System.out.print('*');
        }
        System.out.println();

        j= j +1;
    }
}
```

p.s sorry for been so bad at coding :D and any help would be much appreciated thanks Gareth

Comment: You currently have no code that could print a `.` at all

Comment: What's the output meant to look like?

Comment: Strongly suggest you use a more descriptive title for your questions, e.g. "Outputting a square"

Comment: @gareth, after your teacher take a look at the result can we post the complete answer? just tell us when...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you gotten the program to print an 5x5 square full of asterisks working?

I'd strongly recommend getting that working first. After that, you just need a minor modification to print the dots in between.

For that, instead of always printing an asterisk, you'll need a conditional.

Pseudocode:

```
if(I'm currently on the edge)
  Print an asterisk
else
  Print a dot
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to translate this into real code. Good luck!

Edit, hints on how to determine if you're currently on the edge:

1. You are keeping track of the current row and current column (in order
   to print a square exactly 5x5 characters).
2. The edge consists of the first and last row, and the first and last column.
3. Given hint 1 and hint 2, can you now determine when you are on the edge and when you're not? You'll need to do variable comparison, so read your textbook if you're not familiar with how to compare variables.

Hope that helps. There's really not much more I can say without giving away the exact answer.

Finally, think about your solution *before* coding it. Immediately jumping into coding can be a roadblock, especially when you're a beginner and not too familiar with the language so you get bogged down in the language syntax. Mentally put together the flow of your program, draw pictures, and maybe write pseudocode before you write the actual code. I find that doing this helps me write code easier and reduces the number of bugs that come up.

Comment: thanks alot i Just don't understand how or where to do it but i guess that means Ive got to hit the books

Comment: and yeah i have a square with ***** 5x5

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with a hint. Hope this helps.

Comment: Added one more (hopefully) helpful tip, hehe.

Answer (score 8):

Guidance rather than an answer since it's coursework...

It sounds like you need an `if` statement to decide whether to print `*` or `.`.  The `*` should be printed when you are on the first line or the last line, or at the first column or the last column.

You will find the flow control more intuitive creating a square using a nested `for` loop, e.g.

```
for (int row=0; row<stars; row++)
{
    for (int col=0; col<stars; col++)
    {
        // Do your output here
    }
}
```

Comment: for pedagogical reasons, the rows and cols should probably be revesed as characters are printed row major on the console. As it's a square it would do any diffrence anyway.

Comment: @vedstige: Good point... I'm so used to writing to screen memory that col-then-row is second nature :-)  Changing that in the example.

Answer (score 0):

When either of your loop variables are at their limiting values (both upper and lower) you have to print a * and in other cases you have to print . Use if statement to control this flow. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

All this "use `if` statement", let's do it some other way now. Of course this isn't actually useful, I just want to challenge the idea that you *have to* use control flow, and maybe people stumbling upon this might learn something from it..

First off, here's the code I came up with (it works)

```
    for (int row = 0; row < stars; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < stars; col++) {
            System.out.print((char)((
                    (-col) >> 31 & // encodes the condition: col > 0
                    (-row) >> 31 &
                    (col - (stars - 1)) >> 31 &
                    (row - (stars - 1)) >> 31 & ('*' ^ '.')) ^ '*'));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

The basic principle I used to avoid control flow is that when a negative int is right shifted (with signed shift), the signbit is copied into the bits that are "shifted in" at the left side. A result of that is `x >> 31` (where x is an int) has only two possible outcomes, 0 (if x was nonnegative) and -1 (if x was negative). You can use that principle to turn conditions into bitmasks. You can also do it with unsigned shift and a negation, but you might as well write it the shorter way.
Secondly, I used that `(a ^ b) ^ a = b` and `a ^ 0 = a`.
So when all conditions hold, `'*'` is xored with `'*' ^ '.'`, giving `'.'`, and otherwise `'*'` is xored with zero, giving `'*'`.

Of course, this is just for fun.